# Control sprite from one class with joystick in another

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm working on a SpriteKit game.
Now I have a joystick created in MyScene.m which controls a sprite created in my MyScene.m.
However I'm trying to move that sprite out of MyScene.m into its own class. 
But when I do that, my joystick can no longer move. This is the code in Player.m
and the joystick code in MyScene.m (I imported Player.h but I still can't move the player sprite).
Thanks.

```
#import "Player.h"
#import "MyScene.h"
@implementation Player



- (instancetype)init {
    SKTextureAtlas *atlas =
    [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed: @"characters"];
    SKTexture *texture = [atlas textureNamed:@"walk1"]; texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    if (self = [super initWithTexture:texture])
    { self.name = @"players";

        CGFloat minDiam = MIN(self.size.width, self.size.height); minDiam = MAX(minDiam-16, 4);
        self.physicsBody =
        [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:minDiam/2.0];

        self.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;


        self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
        self.physicsBody.restitution = 1;
        self.physicsBody.friction = 0;
        self.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0;
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

and in MyScene.m the update method is:

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

     if (button) {

 SKNode *controlNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"controlPadNode"];

 SKNode *node = [self childNodeWithName:@"Players"];
    float angle = atan2f (touchY - Y, touchX - ) ;
  SKAction *moveShip=[SKAction moveByX:6*cosf(angle) y:0 duration:0.005];
 [node runAction: moveShip];

 }
 }
```

I have added this code

```
    Player *playerNode=[[Player alloc]init];
    playerNode.name=@"Players";
    [self addChild:playerNode];
```

to my myscene self init.However the joystick still dont move this sprite, only the sprite i built in my MyScene.m

Answer (score 1):

You can add weak reference to joystick to your player class and when you add player to the scene pass joystick to the object (in MyScene.m):

```
Player *playerNode=[[Player alloc]init];
playerNode.name=@"Players";
playerNode.joystic= self.myJoystic;
[self addChild:playerNode];
```

After that in update method in Player class just check the joystick state:

```
if (self.joystic.leftbuttonpressed)
{
    //Left button pressed
}
else if (rightbuttonpressed)
//...
```

You can do it that way. You can also use delegate it depends what works better for you.

Comment: Why a weak reference?

Comment: @trojanfoe because MyScent keep strong reference to joystick and player so player needs just weak ref to joystick, it will work with strong as well. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @greg ok, thanks for replying, sothe update  method to move the player shouldn't be in myscene.m but in player.m. Ok

Comment: @SleepParalysis thats what's in my example the update with if joystick statement is in Player.m file.